# Is there a way to make keytool not prompt for password for the key?

Tags: keytool, jks

I am trying to generate a keystore. I have set a password for the keystore but I am trying to not set a password for the key.

```
keytool -storepass "$password" -keystore ${PFX_broker}server.keystore.jks -alias $brokerCertAlias -validity $validity -genkey -dname "CN=$CN" -noprompt;
```

The above command will prompt me for a key password which defaults to the store pass when I press enter.

Is it possible to skip setting a password for the key altogether and not have a prompt?

Comment: For most keystores, you must have a password to protect (wrap) the key, but you can skip the prompt by specifying it on the command line with `-keypass` like you did the store password. Both of these have the 'feature' that other users/processes on your system can see your password(s) with `ps` or similar or `/proc//cmd`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are parameters to specify key and store passwords

`-keypass <your-pass>` and `-storepass <your-pass>`

E.g.

```
keytool -storepass pass123 -keypass pass123 -keystore keystore.jks -alias myalias -validity 99 -genkey -noprompt
```

[keytool reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/keytool.htm#GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549__CREATEORADDDATATOTHEKEYSTORE-507D49D2)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but I'm facing the same issue and adding -keypass *password* and because I have a store source too, I'm adding -srcstorepass *password* for me works. Try this:

```
keytool -storepass "$password" -keystore ${PFX_broker}server.keystore.jks -alias $brokerCertAlias -validity $validity -genkey -dname "CN=$CN" -noprompt -keypass "$password" -srcstorepass "$password"
```

But might be different in your case.

Comment: Indeed, options `-storepass secret` and `-srcstorepass secret` do the trick. Options `-srckeypass` and `-destkeypass` as shown by `keytool -importkeystore -h` have no effect at all (at least in Java 11). Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

It seems keytool always requires a password for both the store and the key. There is no way around it.

Comment: A password is always required, but the prompt can be avoided as other answers mention.